# Javascript RegExp for matching text which isn't part of HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace, lookbehind

I try to find a way to highlight some text in HTML. The following HTML is given:

```
<div>This text contains matching words like word1 and word2 and xyzword1xyz and word2xyz and xyzword2</div>
```

The list of words which should be surrounded by a `<span>` is:

```
var array = ['word1','word2', 'word1word3'];
```

My current Javascript:

```
$.each(array , function(index, elem){
            if(elem.length<3 || elem === "pan" || elem === "spa" || elem === "span")return true;             
            var re = new RegExp(""+elem+"(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)","gi");
            returnString = returnString.replace(re, "<span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>$&</span>");                
});
```

The resulting div would look like:

```
<div>This text contains matching words like <span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>word1</span> and <span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>word2</span> and xyz<span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>word1</span>xyz and <span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>word2</span>xyz and xyz<span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>word2</span> and finally <span class='markedString colorword1orword2'><span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>word1</span>word3</span></div>
```

Due to the current regexp everthing in the `class='markedString colorword1orword2'` isn't matched.

Problem:
If the array would look like

```
var array = ['word1','word2', 'class'];
```

I would end up with

```
<div>This text contains matching words like <span <span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>class</span>='markedString colorword1orword2'>word1</span> and <span <span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>class</span>='markedString colorword1orword2'>word2</span> and xyz<span <span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>class</span>='markedString colorword1orword2'>word1</span>xyz and <span <span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>class</span>='markedString colorword1orword2'>word2</span>xyz and xyz<span <span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>class</span>='markedString colorword1orword2'>word2</span> and finally <span <span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>class</span>='markedString colorword1orword2'><span <span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>class</span>='markedString colorword1orword2'>word1</span>word3</span></div>
```

This example is somehow constructed, so there could be other words which might be standing in the HTML tags itself.

I need a way to simulate regexp-lookbehind so that I can make a rule like:

> match everything which is not between `<span` and `>` but allow cascaded
>   matchings like `<span>adsa<span>asdsa</span></span>`

Does any regexp-guru has an idea how this could be archieved?

Comment: The words to replace are containing only letters and digits, not any special characters used in RegExp? And the `div` really exists on the page?

Comment: Yes, the `div` is exactly like that on the page. The words to replace are letters and digits and `-` and `_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this (no looping):

```
var $div = $('#the_id_of_ the_div'),
    array = ['word1','word2', 'word1word3'],
    re = new RegExp(array.join('|'), 'gi'),
    divHTML = $div.text().replace(re, "<span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>$&</span>");
$div.html(divHTML);
```

This is just an example, you probably get the `div` from some jQuery object outside the snippet in the post.

---

**EDIT**

If you've a bunch of `div`s in a wrapper, you can do something like this:

```
var array = ['word1','word2', 'word1word3'],
    re = new RegExp(array.join('|'), 'gi');
$('#wrapper div').each(function () {
    var divHTML = $(this).text().replace(re, "<span class='markedString colorword1orword2'>$&</span>");
    $(this).html(divHTML);
    return;
});
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXFGj/).

Comment: GREAT ! Thank you very much - this solved my problem totally!! I had to transform your code to

`var re = new RegExp(array.join('|'), 'gi');
returnString = returnString.replace(re, function(match, contents, offset, s){
    return "<span class='markedString "+allMarkableStrings[match.toLowerCase()]+"'>"+match+"</span>";
});`

and now it works perfect for me !

What a simple but so straight forward idea to do the replacement in one step!

Comment: Oh, I see, I had partly misunderstood your question. I thought the class names similar to words to replace are there just to make things harder...